# facet grid for huge data in list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, ggplot2

I would like to make a facet grid plot of quite long data which is in a list of different dataframes. Here is some example data:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

L <- list()
for (i in 1:10) {
  DATE  <-  seq( as.POSIXct("2016-01-01 21:00:00", tz="UTC"), 
            as.POSIXct("2016-02-01 21:00:00", tz="UTC"), 
            by = 600
            )

  V1  <-  round(runif(length(DATE)) - 0.3,0)
  L[[i]] <- tibble(DATE, V1)
}

names(L) <- LETTERS[1:10]
```

What I acctually need is a `facet_grid()` with each dataframe in one row showing V1 is either 1 or 0, like a barcode or something similar. 
My only success was to bind all list elements to one dataframe with the name of each list element as a new column. This seems to be being kind of circuitous.

```
for (i in 1:10) {
  L[[i]] <- mutate(L[[i]], list.name = names(L)[i] )
}

DF <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, L)

ggplot(DF) + 
  geom_step(aes(DATE, V1), size = 0.1, ) + 
  facet_grid(list.name ~ .)
```

[image: Takes a long time and is not filled]

I would like to have the downsite of the `geom_step()` plot filled like it is at the `geom_area()` (I know it is hard to see in the example). Is there another geom that fits better? Since my data is way longer it takes hours to create the plot. Is there a better way to make a facet_grid() on list elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using `geom_raster`?

```
DF <- map_df(L, I) %>% mutate(V1 = as.factor(V1))

ggplot(DF, aes(x = DATE, y = list.name, fill = V1)) + 
  geom_raster() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("white", "black"))
```

Comment: Hi, thank you! I didn't know the geom_raster. Is there an upper limit for the input data? When I extend the example data to 5 years, I always end up with an empty chart.

Comment: Perhaps the cells become so thin that they cannot be shown. Making the plot wider might help, otherwise you might want to aggregate the data. Perhaps events per month?

Comment: Yes, that's probably the way to go. Thanks a lot!